# How to restrict CRUD functions for not logged users?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, netbeans, crud

I followed this tutorial to do a CRUD application: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFFKMq1kh-M&t=339s
Here is my ManagedBean for it:

```
package model_controller;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;


@Named(value = "studentManagedBean")
@RequestScoped
public class StudentManagedBean {

private int id, wiek;
private String nazwisko, email, adres;

public StudentManagedBean() {
}

public StudentManagedBean(int id, int wiek, String nazwisko, String email, String adres) {
    //konstruktory
    this.id = id;
    this.wiek = wiek;
    this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
    this.email = email;
    this.adres = adres;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getWiek() {
    return wiek;
}

public void setWiek(int wiek) {
    this.wiek = wiek;
}

public String getNazwisko() {
    return nazwisko;
}

public void setNazwisko(String nazwisko) {
    this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getAdres() {
    return adres;
}

public void setAdres(String adres) {
    this.adres = adres;
}

//
public static Connection conn = null;
public static PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
public static ResultSet rs = null;
private String str = "";

//
public static Connection getConnection() {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //Alt+enter
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studenci?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StudentManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StudentManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return conn;
}

public static void closeAll(Connection conn, PreparedStatement pstmt, ResultSet rs) {

    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StudentManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    if (pstmt != null) {
        try {
            pstmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StudentManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    if (rs != null) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StudentManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}


public ArrayList<StudentManagedBean> GetAllStudent() {

    ArrayList<StudentManagedBean> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    str = "SELECT s.id, s.nazwisko, s.wiek, s.adres, s.email FROM student s";
    getConnection();
    try {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(str);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {

            StudentManagedBean st = new StudentManagedBean();
            st.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            st.setNazwisko(rs.getString("nazwisko"));
            st.setWiek(rs.getInt("wiek"));
            st.setAdres(rs.getString("adres"));
            st.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            //
            arr.add(st);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StudentManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        closeAll(conn, pstmt, rs);
    }
    return arr;

}

public void add() {

    getConnection();
    str = "insert into student(nazwisko, wiek, adres, email) values(?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(str);
        pstmt.setString(1, this.getNazwisko());
        pstmt.setInt(2, this.getWiek());
        pstmt.setString(3, this.getAdres());
        pstmt.setString(4, this.getEmail());
        int executeUpdate = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if (executeUpdate > 0) {

            System.out.println("Zaktualizowano dane");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StudentManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        closeAll(conn, pstmt, rs);
    }
}

public void Edit() {

    ArrayList<StudentManagedBean> arrList = GetAllStudent();
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
//        Map<String,String> mapParam = fc.getExternalContext().getInitParameterMap();
//        idStudent = mapParam.get("id");
    int idStudent;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    idStudent = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    //
    for (StudentManagedBean studentManagedBean : arrList) {

        if (studentManagedBean.getId() == idStudent) {

            this.setId(studentManagedBean.getId());//błąd
            this.setNazwisko(studentManagedBean.getNazwisko());
            this.setWiek(studentManagedBean.getWiek());
            this.setAdres(studentManagedBean.getAdres());
            this.setEmail(studentManagedBean.getEmail());
        }
    }

    setId(idStudent);
}

public void update() {

    getConnection();
    str = "update student set nazwisko=?, wiek=?, adres=?, email=? where id=?";
    //        Map<String,String> mapParam = fc.getExternalContext().getInitParameterMap();
    //        idStudent = mapParam.get("id");
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    int idStudent = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

    try {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(str);
        pstmt.setString(1, this.getNazwisko());
        pstmt.setInt(2, this.getWiek());
        pstmt.setString(3, this.getAdres());
        pstmt.setString(4, this.getEmail());
        pstmt.setInt(5, idStudent);

        System.out.println(getNazwisko());
        int executeUpdate = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if (executeUpdate > 0) {

            System.out.println("Zaktualizowano dane");

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StudentManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        closeAll(conn, pstmt, rs);
    }
}

public void delete() {

    getConnection();
    str = "DELETE FROM student where id=?";
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    int idStudent = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

    try {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(str);
        pstmt.setInt(1, idStudent);
        int executeUpdate = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if (executeUpdate > 0) {
            System.out.println("Usunięto dane");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StudentManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        closeAll(conn, pstmt, rs);
    }
}
}
```

It works pretty well, and I wanted to upgrade it - so everyone can see the data, but only logged in users can edit, add and delete records.
I found login tutorial: http://www.journaldev.com/7252/jsf-authentication-login-logout-database-example

How can I restrict edit, add and delete functions only for users that are logged in?
CRUD app is using RequestScope, login uses SessionScope, can i even use two different scopes in one app?
Should I use two different databases for login and students, or should I put it in one database, just two tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rendered` attribute, which by default is set to true.

```
// Your form for inserting data to the database
<h:form rendered="#{studentManagedBean.isLoggedIn}">
  ...
</h:form>

// delete button
<h:commandButton action="#{studentManagedBean.delete()}" 
   rendered="#{studentManagedBean.isLoggedIn}" />
```

You have to add a variable and a method to your managedbean to check whether the user is logged in or not.

```
private boolean loggedIn;
// getter and setter

public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    return loggedIn;
}
```